# invalid literal for int with base 10 - when user dont choose any option

Tags: python

I have this code below and it is working correctly when I choose the option 1, when I choose the option 2 and when I choose other option.

But if user dont choose any option and press enter, I want to show a message "empty" and ask again user to choose an option.

But in this case, when the field is empty I get this error:

```
invalid literal for int with base 10
```

Code:

```
def nav(number):
    while True:
        option = int(raw_input(number))
        if filename == 1:
            createjob()
        elif option == "2":
            print filename
        elif option == "":
            print "empty"
        else:
            print "Option not available"

def main():
    print " 1 - option 1"
    print " 2 - option 2"
    nav("Choose an option:")
main()
```

Comment: Because you're trying to convert `""` to an `int`.

Comment: Please post code that's working as well as you can manage. This code is blatantly wrong; `while True` without `:`, indentation errors, plus you probably did not mean to include the first `while True:` line. It does not work like I think you would expect for option `2`. Are you really sure you think it works for option `2`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the code with corrections. And you are correct I tested now again and its not working for option 2!

Comment: Rob has the right answer below, but can you see the difference between your handling of options 1 and 2 that makes 1 work, but 2 not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have so many while loops... 
Anyway the reason that you are having this issue is because when the user just presses enter "" is trying to be converted to an int. Perhaps you should use strings instead. Ie:

```
def nav(option_number):
    option = raw_input(option_number)
    if option == "1":
        test()
    elif option == "2":
        print option
    elif option == "":
        print "empty"
    else:
        print "option unavailable"

print " 1 - Option 1"
print " 2 - Option 2"
nav("Select option:")
```

Comment: I think you still want a `while True` before the `nav("Select option:")` line. Good call on just using strings though! An obvious solution, but easy to miss...

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` gets data as a string. If you are sure you are always going to get integers. Then typecast. Else check the type using the `type(data_var)` to be sure